# Is it possible to choose one of 2 structures dynamically which are under UNION?

Tags: c

This question is regarding C language concepts.

Existing structure:

```
struct parent{
    char c[4];
    float f;
    double d;
    int flag;

    struct child_old
    {
        int i;
        float l;
    }c1;
}
```

I want to add a new structure under parent (lets call it - child_new).
I use only one of the child structures at a time based on scenario. Not both at a time.
So I can put them under UNION.

Modified structure:

```
struct parent{
    char c[4];
    float f;
    double d;
    int flag;

    union{
        struct child_old
        {
            int i;
            float j;
        }c1;

        struct child_new
        {
            int i;
            float j;
            char c[32];
            double d;

        }c2;
    }UU;
}
```

Here my requirement is, based on struct member "flag" value (0/1), I need to decide which child structure I need to use.

This is because:

1. There is huge data stored in my file system of type parent structure. There should not be any problem while reading them.
2. while using child_old, I dont want to consume extra space needed by child_new.

Is it possible in C?
Or is there any work around solution?

Comment: That's fine. But if you don't intend to add more members to the `union`, you should have `bool flag`, not `int`. This guarantees it will not have any other value than `0` or `1`. If you want to extend, use an `enum` and rename `flag` to something more clear, e.g. `type`.

Comment: @Olaf `bool` limits future extensions. `int` or `enum` is designing for extensibility, and generally a good idea when designing protocols or file formats.

Comment: @slim: Please read may comment **to the end**! What new do you tell here? There are use-cases no extension will happen and then `bool` with its only two values is safer.

Comment: @olaf Don't want an extended chat, but just pointing out that "if you don't intend to add more members to the union" is a bad default position to take.

Comment: @slim: Not for an experience programmer who know what he is doing. There are sometimes good reasons to do so! For example safety-critical code. Without more background we cannot know and my comment covers all.

Comment: @stragateur, both of them exists in same file system. I know, reading old structure may not cause problem. Looking for any possibility to reduce sizeof parent if child_old is used.

Comment: @Aryas nothing in your question mentions files. But I don't think you should edit this one now -- it is a valid question in itself. Ask another question about reading structs from files, if you have one.

Answer (score 4):

What you've written is fine, and you would consume it with something like:

```
switch(p.flag) {
   case CHILD_OLD:
       // work with p.c1
       break;
   case CHILD_NEW:
       // work with p.c2
       break;
}
```

However, your full struct will always be big enough for the largest member of the union. So when you use c1, you still have enough space for c2 allocated. But, at least you're not allocating `sizeof(c1) + sizeof(c2)` each time.

If you really want to allocate more or less space depending on which variant each record uses, you'll need to put a pointer in the struct, and dynamically allocate a separate record for the child elements.

---

All of this does mean that if you're reading byte arrays from disk then casting them to a struct:

```
  parent *p = (parent*) addressOfSomeDataReadFromAFile;
```

(Not a great idea, but not unusual in the wild)

... then expanding the `parent` struct using the union technique will not generally work. Your existing files will represent a record as fewer bytes than the new struct.

Comment: From the wording of the two requirements in the question, it seems the OP is reading/writing entire structures directly to/from files.  So a pointer to a dynamically-allocated structure couldn't be done without a lot of effort.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that's an interesting observation, and I will address it.

Comment: Hopefully OP is not using such a terrible technique, but if so, then they'll need to update their code to translate the previous code's layout to the new code's layout.

Comment: @M.M sorry; rusty C; fixed.

Comment: Yes I agree on how UNION consumes memory. Is there any workaround to that without using pointers? I got this idea but I cant afford to append even a single member to parent. I need enhancement to use child_new in lieu of child_old yet times (for new parent structures). Because there are a lot many old structures in file system which cannot be modified.

Comment: @Aryas are you doing something similar to what's described in the second half of the answer? If so it probably deserves a separate question which specifies this clearly. Short answer is that you either need a "struct parentv2", or adopt a more sophisticated way of reading/writing files.

Comment: `parent *p = (parent*) addressOfSomeDataReadFromAFile;` might cause problems related to pointer aliasing.

Comment: @slim I'd guess there's a lot of legacy data written to files using `struct child_old`, more data is needed so the larger `struct child_new` was created, and there's now a need to write code that can handle both structures. The problem is without versioning the structure from the beginning, that's almost impossible to solve unless the code can somehow know in advance which structure is stored in the file being read.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665015/how-to-handle-changing-data-structures-on-program-version-update

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes, but we're speculating about the actual problem, which is why I'd like OP to write another question.

Comment: @slim That would make this an XY problem, I suppose.  The OP assumed a union would solve his problem, so he asked about unions.

Answer (score 1):

Given your requirement of

> 2. while using child_old, I dont want to consume extra space needed by child_new.

you can't use a union.

Per **6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**, paragraph 16 of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its
>   members.

Thus the size of the union would be that of the largest member.

Note also, as pointed out in the comments, that changing the union may also impact the padding/alignment of other elements of any structure containing that union.

Comment: In general there could be trailing padding, so the size of union may exceed the largest member

Comment: @M.M True, but the wording of the standard implies to me that such padding would be considered part of the "size ... sufficient to contain [that member]".  Whether or not any structure or union containing the union in question has padding could also be an issue.

Comment: I was referring to your addition "the size of the union would be that of the largest member", which may not be true

Comment: @M.M Are you referring to any padding inserted into the enclosing structure?  That would be another issue, I'd say.

Comment: @M.M OK, I tried to clarify my answer some.  I'm not sure how to account for such padding if it's not represented by `sizeof( union_in_question )`.

Comment: The padding is represented by that `sizeof`. Not sure which comments you refer to in the edit, I have not mentioned "structure containing that union" at any stage.

Comment: Yeah I agree UNION would take largest member. Is there any workaround to that with out changing parent structure members? I cant even afford to append a single member to parent. I need enhancement to use child_new in lieu of child_old yet times (for new parent structures). Old structure in file system cannot be modified.

Comment: Any work around like using #if and comment out child_old when value of parent.flag suggests to use child_new would work for me.

Comment: @stargateur That's a typo while framing the question. I tried to simplify a big requirement into a small chunk and framed question. Then typo happened. You can have a look at it now.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it is neither pretty nor effective. It is considered bad practice to use unions for storing different kinds of unrelated data. And as already mentioned, the size will be that of the biggest member of the union, so it is not memory-efficient either.

Instead, here is a more sensible solution:

```
struct parent {
    char c[4];
    float f;
    double d;
    int flag;

    void* data;
}

...

struct parent x;
x.data = malloc(sizeof(struct child_old));
struct child_old* co_ptr = x.data;
co_ptr->i = ...;
```

Here the `void*` points at the actual data which is allocated elsewhere. You will also need some means to keep track of which kind of data that is stored there.

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly but it work.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

enum Type {
  A,
  B,
};

struct Base {
  enum Type type;
};

struct A {
  char foo[4];
};

struct B {
  char bar[8];
};

struct BaseA {
  struct Base base;
  struct A a;
};

struct BaseB {
  struct Base base;
  struct B b;
};

int main(void) {
  int fd = open("foo.bar", O_RDONLY);
  if (fd == -1) {
    return 1;
  }

  union {
    struct Base base;
    struct BaseA base_a;
    struct BaseB base_b;
  } buffer;
  if (read(fd, &buffer.base, sizeof buffer.base) != sizeof buffer.base) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (buffer.base.type == A) {
    if (read(fd, &buffer.base_a.a, sizeof buffer.base_a.a) !=
        sizeof buffer.base_a.a) {
      return 1;
    }
  } else if (buffer.base.type == B) {
    if (read(fd, &buffer.base_b.b, sizeof buffer.base_b.b) !=
        sizeof buffer.base_b.b) {
      return 1;
    }
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

You could do what you want in if statement. Add every `Base_A` in an array, and all `Base_B` in another one.

If you don't want padding use something like `#pragma pack(n)`.

Comment: OK, missed that.  I'll delete my comments - and give you an upvote.  Not sure why you got the downvote - probably someone who doesn't understand how ugly structure versioning is.